# Why does a narrow line of falling water seem drop drop when quickly looking at it from top to the bottom?

Tags: water, vision

When I was under the shower I experienced when I look quickly at a single line of water falling from one pore (from top to the bottom) it looks "drop drop" instead of continuous. Why is it like that?

Comment: Is your shower head clean?

Comment: This may help - https://www.shutterstock.com/video/clip-18478558-slow-motion-shot-shower-head-flowing-water

Comment: I think so. If it wasn't then I should've seen non-continuous water even with just looking at it without moving my head (quickly or not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stream of water is not as continuous and uniform as you might imagine.

If you are looking at the falling water with an electric light run from the mains supply on it is a strobe effect because the intensity of the light is varying due to the alternating voltage supply.

You can enhance the effect by spreading out the fingers of a hand and then moving the vertically orientated hand up and down rapidly.

With sunlight or a dc powered light source you can see the effect because the water stream is not uniform and reflects light in different directions for which you the response of your eye is fast enough to observe.
Again the effect can be enhanced by observing the stream through a waving spread out hand.

The effect can easily be seen in the frame from a video.

[image]

Comment: By waving spread out hand do you mean the effect when you move your finger rapidly in front of a turned-on cathode ray tube monitor with house lights off?

Comment: @SnackExchange Yes. By waving you are strobing the light. With the cro you are observing the build up of the display on the screen.

Comment: But in the strobing effect I should see the non-continuous water without moving my eye. Why do I see it when I move my eye rapidly in the direction of water?